# Cross-checking for missing data - missing data, but not really?

Tags: python, dataset, missing-data

I have been sitting with this issue for quite some time now, and I am seeking help. I have been working with data from the SEC's EDGAR, wherein I have managed to download CIK numbers, dates, company names and the ftp path to each of a company's annual report. All in all, I have 7,000 rows that I am supposed to download.

I run my code in Python to download these text files (by reading the ftp path) and saving them locally on my computer. The names of these files is equal to the CIK number, date and company name split by a '-'.

Hereafter, I wrote the following in order to cross-check that I have downloaded all the 7,000 text files:

```
import os
import csv

tenk_path = "D:/10ks/1 download/"

arr = os.listdir(tenk_path)

csvfile = "data.csv"

with open(csvfile, "a", newline="") as fp:
    wr = csv.writer(fp, dialect='excel')
    wr.writerow(['cik', 'name', 'year', 'unique_key'])

for name in arr:
    main_name = name.split("-")
    unique_key = str(main_name[0])+str(main_name[-1])
    csvRow = [main_name[0],
              main_name[1],
              main_name[-1],
              unique_key]
    with open(csvfile, "a", newline="") as fp:
        wr = csv.writer(fp, dialect='excel')
        wr.writerow(csvRow)
    print(name)
```

I then concatenate (in excel for easeness) the CIK and date (year) which should be unique for all companies. I then make sure that there are no whitespaces by using =TRIM, and converting the textstrings into numbers by =VALUE.

By doing this, I match the concatenation of the CIK number and the year for the files I was SUPPOSED to download, with the concatenation of the ones I did download (6,994). By doing so, I obtain that I find matches for all 7,000 - which does not make sense in my head at all? I have already made sure that no paths etc. are duplicates to begin with, so that can't be it.

Can anyone help? The data can be found here:

https://ufile.io/rhuv2

Answer (score 1):

I was a bit quick on the remark of having reviewed any duplications to begin with. I solved it by forcefully forcing Excel to filter based uniquely on the concatenation alone. However, afterwards I noticed that some ftp paths were duplicates - therefore an error on the SEC's EDGAR part.